# Loop through the days of the week

Tags: java

I was wondering if someone could tell me if it's possible to loop through the days of the week after 6 inputs of product or/and 6 inputs of quantity are input. So basically the program displays Monday and then loops 6 times and then goes to Tuesday loops 6 times and then Wednesday. If it is possible could I get a few ideas??? I would really appreciate some help. I have googled with no luck and that's because I know i'm not asking google the right question.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

      public class Mailorder {

         public static void main(String[] args) {

         //create a scanner
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

         //declare variables

         double product1 = 3.75;
         double product2 = 5.95;
         double product3 = 8.75;
         double product4 = 6.92;
         double product5 = 8.75;
         double product6 = 7.87;
         double sum2 = 0;
         int sum1 = 0;
         double total = 0.00;
         int product;
         int quantity;

         //Monday
         System.out.print("Monday");
         System.out.println();

         //read in product # 
         System.out.print("Enter a product number: ");
         product = input.nextInt();

         //read in quantity sold
         System.out.print("Enter quantity sold: ");
         quantity = input.nextInt();


         //keep reading data until the input is 0
         while (quantity != -1) {
                 sum1 += quantity;

         //switch case
         switch (product) 
        {
         case 1: total = product1 * quantity; break;
         case 2: total = product2 * quantity; break;
         case 3: total = product3 * quantity; break;
         case 4: total = product4 * quantity; break;
         case 5: total = product5 * quantity; break;
         case 6: total = product6 * quantity; break;
        }

       sum2 +=total;

       //read the next data 
       System.out.print("Enter a product number: ");
             product = input.nextInt();

       System.out.print("Enter quantity sold: ");
             quantity = input.nextInt();

        }   
      //print results
      System.out.println("The total retail value of all products sold last week $" + sum2);

    }
  }
```

Comment: You're on the right track with your use of the word “loop.”  Try searching for "java loop".

Comment: You might benefit from using an enumeration if it's not over your head.

Comment: You can use one more input from user whether its monday or tuesday and so on and then loop will work as it is right now

Comment: I have tried what you suggested but the loop doesn't print properly.

Comment: can you give me an example??

Comment: By the way, use [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for money amounts. `double` uses floating-point technology to trade away accuracy for speed of execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for unformatted text, i am replying from mobile.

I think what you need is this operator "%"

Inside your while loop you can increment a count

```
int count=0;
String currentDay="Monday";
String nextDay;


// your while loop start here

count++;

if(count%6 == 0)
{
    switch(currentDay)
    {
    case "Monday": nextDay="Tuesday"; break;
    //etc
    }
currentDay = nextDay;
}
```

% operator will give you reminder of a division.

Comment: Thank you that seems more of what I am looking for. Now to try and get it to work.

Comment: I have added this but now I'm getting errors at the end of the program. sorry for the formatting it shows correctly when inputting but when displayed it's wrong                                                                                     //keep reading data until the input is -1
   while (quantity != -1) 
    sum1 += quantity;
   
   count++;

   if(count%6 == 0);  {
   System.out.println("Tuesday"); // Tuesday
   }
   if(count%5 == 1); {
   System.out.println("Wednesday");// Wednesday{
   }

Comment: It is not exact code which I gave. It is an idea about how the % operator can be used. I will edit the answer

Comment: ok we are getting somewhere finally. I feel very close to what I am trying to achieve. Now it loops once and then print Tuesday Wednesday on top of each other. I do appreciate the help. I have a feeling my issue now lies where the loop starts and ends

Comment: so I can use a switch statement for it??

Comment: Yes. Inside the if(count%6 ==0) or if(count%6==5). Code inside the if will execute once every 6 times. Google "modulus" operator, to get a better understanding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103885/discussion-between-jake-and-cozimetzer).

Answer (score 3):

## `DayOfWeek` enum

The [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum defines seven objects, one for each day of the week, numbered 1-7 for Monday-Sunday.

An [`EnumSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) is a highly optimized implementation of `Set` for collecting enum objects.

```
EnumSet<DayOfWeek> dows = EnumSet.allOf( DayOfWeek.class );  // Collect all seven day-of-week objects, in order Monday-Sunday.
```

Loop that set.

```
for( DayOfWeek dow : dows ) {
    String dowName = dow.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.US ) ;  // Generate localized string for the name of the day-of-week.
    System.out.println( dowName ) ;  
    … // Ask for product code and do your math
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an inner loop:

```
for(--- each day of the week ---) 
    // do something

    for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

To find what are the days of the week (how to implement the 1st loop), look at class Calendar: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getActualMinimum(int)

```
int firstDay = Calendar.getInstance().getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
int lastDay = Calendar.getInstance().getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Comment: Thank you I will look into that. I do appreciate the help!!

Comment: I am looking into calendar and I am not able to use that because we go over that later on. Is there a way to use a switch statement or use a loop without calendar??

Comment: Since Java 8 there is a enum [`java.time.DayOfWeek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) that you can use instead of `Calendar`. The nice thing about it is, that your loop becomes simpler by using a for-each loop.

Answer (score 2):

**DayOfWeek enum**

The DayOfWeek enum defines seven objects, one for each day of the week, numbered 1-7 for Monday-Sunday and it can be accessed even easier:

```
for(DayOfWeek day : DayOfWeek.values())
{
   //Your code goes here
}
```